# I sent $5 worth of Eth from Coinbase to Bittrex. And it doesn't show any balance after 10hours

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, coinbase

Hey I sent $5 worth of Eth from Coinbase to Bittrex. And it still doesn't show any balance. The transaction show confirmed but no balanced n Bittrex after 10Hours. Anybody can help?

Comment: You should contact Bittrex support. We can't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

Better to contact Bittrex administration. I had the same problem with Burstcoin and after 2 or 3 emails they gave me back my coins.